# How to extract the parent folder in bash script?

Tags: bash, path, pwd

In a bash script, I want to extract the 2 last folders of the pwd.

I did this :

```
value=`pwd`
echo "you are here : $value"
echo "the folder is: ${value##*/}"
```

To have this :

```
you are here: /home/user/folder1/folder2
the folder is folder2
```

Now I want to extract the parent folder (folder1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, using *pre-defined* variable `PWD`:

```
value="$PWD"
echo "you are here :$value"
echo "the folder is: ${value##*/}"
echo "the parent folder is $(basename "${PWD%/*}")"
```

You can replace the last line with:

```
dir="${PWD%/*}"
echo "the parent folder is ${dir##*/}"
```

The backquote (`) is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g.

```
foo=`command`
```

The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside $() is less surprising, and $() is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: No need to run a separate command (`basename`) for that. Bash parameter substitution can do it on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
value=`pwd`
echo "you are here: $value"
echo "the folder is ${value##*/}"
parent="${value%/*}"
echo "the parent folder is ${parent##*/}"
```

in order to get this:

```
you are here: /home/user/folder1/folder2
the folder is folder2
the parent folder is folder1
```

Comment: Whe are now in 2020. The backquote is used in the old-style command substitution. The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside $() is less surprising, and $() is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: I know. But that was the OP's choice, not mine. It's better to keep the parts that aren't directly affected by the actual answer as they are so not to confuse the asker.

Comment: Thanks both of you ! I'm newbie learning it. Better learn the good way to doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using regular expressions:
If you want to know how the regular expression works I suggest you take a look on [this site](https://regex101.com/r/dbxKDo/1).

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(pwd)
regex='.*\/([a-zA-Z0-9\._]*)\/([a-zA-Z0-9\._]*)$'
echo You are here: $value
echo The folder is: ${value##*/}
[[ $value =~ $regex ]]
echo Parent folder: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```